# Looping through rows

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have an app that displays a number of rows of products. Right now it's hardcoded to use three html rows. I really want to build a template for one row, and loop through and populate as many as I need to show up. I was thinking this is a job for Web UI loops (think fruitsearch example). Or do I want to build the template and make it a web component and pass my data to that? I'm really not sure what the best structure is here. This is a bit of an open-ended question, but what's the ideal structure for populating multiple rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

Use Web Components when you need re-usability, or if your rows have complex logic or layout associated with them.

Given your description of "rows of products" I would use a Web Component for each product row and possibly another Web Component to keep track of all the product rows. For instance, if this is a product search result page, the SearchResultComponent could have a title, a list of ProductRowComponents and the number of results found, and each ProductRowComponent could have a name, a price and an image.

This would make it easier to handle the complexity involved as well as allow re-usability (i.e. using multiple ProductRowComponents).